# Android windowmanager LayoutParams

Tags: android

I am using this set of layoutParams:

```
    final LayoutParams myParams = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

my popup dialog appears when I use this set of params however, when I try to type something in the background (other apps), I noticed I couldn't type anything, I tried messing around with the layoutparams but could not find the correct one to use,

Which params will allow me to use the keyboard on both the popup and the background application?

Comment: I don't think LayoutParams manage the keyboard itself. It appears when you select an editable and focusable  field, so if your pop-up blocks anything behind it, then you can't use the keyboard in the background

Comment: Post your popup dialog code because you can manage soft keyboard on editable field you can't be direct set it to layout params.